# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array in LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am currently working on a Log in form but the thing here is that when I enter an invalid username this errors comes up.

```
Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.
```

On this line of code:

```
bool isSame = hasher.CompareStringToHash(txtPassword.Text, hashedPassword);
```

Here is the full code

```
public void verifyAccount()
        {
            var hashedPassword = getPassword();

            var hasher = new Hasher();

            hasher.SaltSize = 16;
            bool isSame = hasher.CompareStringToHash(txtPassword.Text, hashedPassword);

            if (isSame==false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName or Password");
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
                this.Hide();
                main.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
            }   
        }
```

And the This is the method for searching a such username at the same time getting their password password in the database.

```
public string getPassword()
        {

            DataClasses1DataContext myDbContext = new DataClasses1DataContext(dbPath);


            var password = (from user in myDbContext.Accounts
                           where user.accnt_User == txtUser.Text
                           select user.accnt_Pass).FirstOrDefault();

             if (password == null) {
                 return "z"; 
             }

            return password;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 data should be 4-bytes aligned. So for example the "z" that you're returning should be Base64 encoded and padded like this: "eg==" to be Base64 compliant. You should do the same type of padding for the real hashed password.

Answer (score 1):

`hasher.CompareStringToHash` probably expects the `hashedPassword` to be a proper Base64-encoded string. The "z" string you use is invalid in this case.

I'd suggest changing your code like this:

```
    private void VerifyAccount()
    {
        if (!ValidateCredentials(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid user name or password");
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateCredentials(string userName, string password)
    {
        string existingPassword = GetUserPassword(userName);
        if (existingPassword == null)
            return false;

        var hasher = new Hasher { SaltSize = 16 };
        bool passwordsMatch = hasher.CompareStringToHash(password, existingPassword);

        return passwordsMatch;
    }

    private string GetUserPassword(string userName)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext dataContext = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var password = (from user in dataContext.Accounts
                        where user.accnt_User == userName
                        select user.accnt_Pass).FirstOrDefault();
        return password;
    }
```

Comment: I need to have a dummy return value because if there's no User exist in that database it will just return a message saying it has a wrong password.

Comment: I'd suggest not to return a dummy value, but return null instead. Then, in the verifyAccount() method you can compare the return value to null. If it is null, then the user does not exist (provided you don't allow nulls in the database). If it is not null, then you can safely check the hash and thus tell whether the password is correct.

Comment: any idea how would I implement that? all I have is along messy codes of if statements

Comment: I edited my answer and pasted the version that I'm suggesting. Hope this helps.

Comment: I suppose you have a couple of textboxes and a button on your form. In this case you should call VerifyAccount() in the code that handles the Button.Click event. The VerifyAccount() method will deal with everything else :)

Comment: Wow nice, I never though you could actually that with booleans, I think I should learn more about bool's, btw what does the bang operator do in this ? (!ValidateCredentials(txtUser.Text, txtPassword.Text)

Answer (score 0):

You should just let `GetPassword()` return `null` if the password isn't found. The next problem though is that `CompareStringToHash()` will fail if you pass in a null password, so instead of

```
        bool isSame = hasher.CompareStringToHash(txtPassword.Text, hashedPassword);

        if (isSame==false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName or Password");
        }
```

You do

```
        if (hashedPassword == null || hasher.CompareStringToHash(txtPassword.Text, hashedPassword)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid UserName or Password");
        }
```

If `hashedPassword` is `null` the `if` statement will be exited before it tries to execute the `CompareStringToHash()` so you won't get an exception. `CompareStringToHash()` will only execute if `hashedPassword` is not `null`. Then provided you've stored a valid string (which you will have because you are creating it will Encrypto) it should all work - and without a lot of messy `if` statements :o)